# Expresiones Regulares para correo electrónico en Java

Tags: java, android, regex

Estoy implementando la parte de valores aceptados para un correo electrónico

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
```

hasta aqui todo bien el valor de un correo seria este c.stackoverflow@gmai.com por decir algo,

pero me gustaría que la variable pattern, pueda almacenar el siguiente string c.stackoverflow@gmai.com/valoranexado

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})*/$");
```

Agregue el slash en la parte final y si me acepta el slash pero al momento de mandar valoranexado no me permite (Yo se que me falta hacer referencia después del slash)

Agregue lo siguiente `("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})*/[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)$");`

Pero no me deja Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que la expresion regular me permita agregar despues del correo lo siguiente ejemplo c.stackoverflow@gmai.com/valoranexado

---

```
public static JODO convertJODO(String jod) throws InvalidJodException {
    JODO jOD = new JODO();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\\\w+]+(\\\\.[\\\\w-]{1,62}){0,126}@[\\\\w-]{1,63}(\\\\.[\\\\w-]{1,62})+/[\\\\w-]+$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jod);

    if (matcher.find() == true) {
        System.out.println("Format Valid");
    } else {
        throw new InvalidJodException("Not Format Invalid");
    }
```

Comment: Carlos, es practica aquí de agregar cambios a la pregunta o respuesta en vez de abrir una variedad de respuestas. Ten en mente que el resultado al fin queda como ayuda para otros. :) Si la respuesta te solucionaba el problema, lo puedes aceptar como respuesta, para que los otros usuarios saben que fue la solución al fin.

Answer (score 1):

Pruebalo con lo siguiente:

```
email.matches("^[\\w-+]+(\\.[\\w-]{1,62}){0,126}@[\\w-]{1,63}(\\.[\\w-]{1,62})+/[\\w-]+$")
```

Los limites existen a causa de que nombres de dominios permiten hasta 127 segmentos separados por "." con un tamaño hasta 63 octets. [\w] es equivalente a [_a-zA-Z0-9].

Comment: Hola stefan, fijate que me marca un error ("^[\\w-+] al inicio may not be used inside character range.  Sabes que podria ser?

Comment: Eso es resultado de copiar y pegar el código en tu IDE, que te hace el "favor" de escapar los ´\\´ de nuevo, duplicandolos a `\\\\\`. Siempre hay que cuidarse cuando uno copia código usando un IDE.